# Hierarchial datasource in Kendo UI treeview

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am new to Kendo UI and I am trying to implement a tree view using Hierarchial datasource in Kendo UI. Following is the code sample

```
var elementList= " {text:\"ABC\"},{text:\"DEF\",items:[{text:\"childDEF\"}]}";


var dataDefault=new kendo.data.HierarchialDataSource(
                        {
                              data:elementList
                        });

$("#grouptree").kendoTreeView({
                       dataSource:dataDefault
                       });
```

The text in elementList is formed dynamically. I have my result in an array and then the data from the array is stored in this variable. I need to show this in a tree hierarchy. But when I run it, I am getting "object doesn't support this property or method" error in the line "data:elementList".

AM i missing something here like some other parameters or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You are giving the data source a string. Change elementList to a regular JavaScript array. You have also misspelled HierarchicalDataSource (there is a "c" missing). Here is the fixed code: http://jsbin.com/usoqoh/1/edit